# Start task processes in parallel, exit parallel block when one is rejected. SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, approval

I currently have two task processes running in parallel steps. I would like to be able to move onto the rejection stage immediately if one is rejected. Currently both tasks have to be completed for the parallel block to end, which requires one approver to interact with their task, even if the other has already been rejected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've already come across this but I think the answer you are looking for lies in a solution provided by [John Underwood](https://threewill.com/waiting-change-workflow/). By making use of variables you are able to exit the parallel block once the boolean variable changes to the other value (true or false).

I've used this in the way the video explains it, but maybe you can benefit from this functionality in your case by setting a variable (is Rejected) to "yes" once one of the users rejects it.

Hope this helps,